# How do I reach an IP address on my LAN which is two routers away?

Tags: wireless-networking, lan

In order to connect to my Android Galaxy 10.1 tab, I'm trying to use [WiFi Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dooblou.WiFiFileExplorerPRO&hl=en), which sets up the tablet as being a file server on the WiFi LAN, accessable by local IP address.

The app says that I can connect to my tablet from my Ubuntu desktop computer by going to 192.168.0.21:8000. But whenever I try that address in my browser, it says "Unable to connect".

I think this is because of the way my WiFi network is set up. I have an Aterm router which does not have a WiFi option on it. Connected to that is a Logitec wireless router.

So the connection I am trying to make is:

```
Ubuntu Desktop -> Aterm Router -> Logitec Wireless router -> tablet device
```

I think what's happening is that the Logitec is assigning the IP address to the tablet, so the Aterm router doesn't know about it, and the Desktop can't find it.

How do I go from my Desktop, though my routers, to talk to the tablet at it's assigned IP address (it's using static IP, by the way)?

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way is to connect the desktop to the wireless router if it has LAN ports. Otherwise you need to use [Port Forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) or [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).

Also -- what is the reason for having 2 routers?

Edit: based on OP's comments, it appears that the second router is not set as a router, but access point. What I am suggesting is:

```
                              192.168.0.1 (to Atern Router)
                              192.168.1.1 (interface to  tablet and desktop)
                                  *
 internet -> Aterm Router -> Logitec Wireless router -> tablet device   (192.168.1.x)
                                  |
                                  | --------------- > Ubuntu Desktop  (192.168.1.y)
```

**That however didn't solve the issue, it seems that something else is blocking the connection**

Comment: Router A is also the optical cable modem. It's required by my ISP in order to connect. It has a WiFi option, but to enable it, I have to pay a ridiculous monthly service fee. So I just got a second router with WiFi for a few bucks.

Comment: Ok, I see. But then you can just connect the desktop to the second router (I assume it has LAN ports), this way the desktop and the tablet would be on the same local network and should "see" each other.

Comment: @Dave M G - Are you able to ping the IP address of the tablet? Am guessing you are on the same subnet as well.

Comment: @lupincho: The problem with that solution, unless I'm mistaken, is that then I'd have to find a way for devices connecting by WiFi to connect out to the internet by going through the computer and finding the router. So it's kind of the same problem, just going a different direction.

Comment: @DaveMG: It shouldn't be a problem if the second router gets IP address from the first and devices connected by WiFi or LAN to the second modem get their IP addresses from the second. Usually when everything is set to get IP addresses automatically via DHCP the routers handle this and it should be transparent to the user and devices. Try to connect the desktop to the second router (you said that something has an fixed IP, if it is the desktop, either set it to automatic IP or choose fixed IP in the range served by the second router). If that connects to internet, most WiFi devices would work.

Comment: @lupincho: That's what I thought, bit it doesn't seem to be that way.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: I can't ping the address. It says "Destination Host Unreachable".

Comment: @DaveMG Then there is something wrong with the router or client settings. Could you post the local IP addresses, gateways and masks of the routers, desktop and tablet. Also, which devices need to have fixed IP address. Obviously don't post the global (routable) address of the first router.

Comment: @lupincho: Sorry, I'm not totally clear what you are asking for. The IP of the tablet is 192.168.0.21, port 8000. The IP of the first router, which is also the gateway, is 192.168.0.1. The netmask is 255.255.255.0. Does that answer your request?

Comment: @DaveMG: The first router -- is this the wired (from your ISP) or wireless? What is the IP address of the other router and the desktop. Can the tablet access internet now?

Comment: Desktop:192.168.0.2. Non-wifi "main" router: 192.168.0.1. Wifi router: 192.168.0.9. Tablet: 192.168.0.21. All are static IP. Also, my computer seems to have only one ethernet port, currently connected to the "main" router, so it would seem to not be possible to have it connect directly to both main and wifi routers.

Comment: @DaveMG: I see... the second router is set as an access point. This is what you can do (write down the current settings before starting): Keep the 2 routers as they are. Set the wi-fi router to assign IP addresses by DHCP, e.g. in the 192.168.1. range. Then set both tablet and desktop  **to obtain IP address automatically** from the second router, with the desktop being connected by LAN to that router only. Then both devices should be able to access internet and see each other. The only issue is that they won't necessarily have fixed IP addresses, but this could be done by fixed DHCP lease.

Comment: Thanks for your continued advice. I don't know what you mean by "Set the desktop to connect to the wi-fi router by LAN and to obtain IP address automatically". I've been poking around various LAN settings on the computer, but I don't see how I tell the computer to connect to the wi-fi router in any way other than typing it's IP (192.168.0.9) in a browser.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your chat request - I was trying to figure out how to execute on your suggested instructions.

Comment: What I meant was to physically connect the desktop to the wireless router using the LAN port of the router; and to set the desktop to obtain IP address automatically. Basically what I am suggesting is to have the second router behave as router, not as it is right now; and to have both devices connected to that router; see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I've set it up as you suggested, but I'm still not seeing the tablet, and so I'm wondering if maybe I've misdiagnosed the problem. I'm wondering if there is some kind of firewall or something on the device blocking incoming connections.

Comment: Yes, it could be that too. Typically if 2 devices are on the same network (behind one router as in my suggestion), they should see each other unless something is blocking the connection. You may want to check if the second (wifi) router is not blocking something or whether the tablet is not blocking something. The router GUI may show something. For example, check if things like uPnP are enabled. Also try to check if you can connect to the tablet from itself.

Comment: @lupincho - The subnet the Aterm is assigned is different to that of the Linksys router. The fact that Dave M G is unable to ping the IP address would indicate it is an IP addressing issue as opposed to something being blocked unless there is a firewall enabled on the tablet.

Comment: @Dave M G - Are you able to ping the access point? I have a similar setup and what I have done is assign a static IP address to my access point as I did with all other devices. I see you can access the access point by its IP address. Is the access point set up to issue IP addresses to any device that connects to it?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: I've set the Wireless Router to be in "Access Point" mode, and it has a static IP of 192.168.0.9. I don't really know how it works, but I assume that it assigns IP addresses to any wireless device that connects to it. My tablet has a static IP of 192.168.0.21, and it connects via the WiFi access point/router in order to get to the internet. I just tested now, and it seems I can't ping the WiFi access point/router at 192.168.0.9. So I guess there's a problem there.

Comment: I tried it again today... and it magically worked this time. I don't have any idea what I did between yesterday and today. Not sure if that means I should mark this answer as correct...?

Comment: I'd say wait couple of days, if it still works, then it probably was a correct answer.